# Manually entered Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS entry only sometimes forwards to Ubuntu VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I have a Ubuntu VM that I'm turning into a web server. I don't want this on the domain so it doesn't automatically get a DNS entry.

As such I've created one for it in the Forward Lookup Zone, but alas it only sometimes works. Half the time I ping the machine by name it will work. Then I'll come into work the next morning and find that the DNS lookup is no longer working.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

I tried nslookup:

```
>nslookup cc
5.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
    primary name server = localhost
    responsible mail addr = nobody.invalid
    serial = 1
    refresh = 600 (10 mins)
    retry = 1200 (20 mins)
    expire = 604800 (7 days)
    default TTL = 10800 (3 hours)
Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.1.5

Name: cc.AD1.local
Address: 192.168.1.66

>ping cc
Ping request could not find host cc. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Have you tried using tools like `nslookup` to see if the DNS server is working right?

Comment: @NathanC I hadn't, but now I have.

Comment: Does this occur on all clients or just some/one?

Comment: @dbr This problem only seems to happen from my client. I have tested other clients when I am unable to ping via name, and they work just fine while mine cannot resolve the name. I suppose I could just add to my hosts file, but it'd be nice to know what is going on.

Comment: what happens if you use the FQDN to ping the server over just the hostname portion?

Comment: @Rex When it's not working, pinging the FQDN responds the same as simply pinging the host. When it is working, they both work.